# Build a Separate Java Class Hierarchy

Tags: java, object, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

Every other class in Java inherits from the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class.

**Is it possible to add a second, completely separate, class hierarchy in Java based around my own `FastObject` class?**

My original goal in doing so was to create smaller, faster objects with less functionality specifically designed for certain algorithms. But let me be clear, I am not interested in whether or not this is a "good idea".  I just want to know if it is possible; I have not been able to find a way to do so.  Would it require a change to the JVM? New boot classpath functionality? Is the real solution to ignore `Object` and look at replacing `java.lang.Class`? Would using a direct Java compiler instead of a VM make my job any easier?

To be clear, I don't just want to edit the root `Object` class. That would require potentially re-writing the entire Java library. I don't want to replace the current hierarchy, I just want to create a separate one I can use in the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

All created classes extend another class, either explicitly or implicitly.  If you create a class and explicitly define which class it extends, then it extends that class.  If not, then it implicitly extends `Object`.  There is no way around this, just as there is no way to overload operators or anything of that sort.  It is a fundamental design decision of the Java programming language.

All classes extend `Object`.  The only things that don't are primitive types.  The exception to this is `Object` itself, of course, which does not extend itself.

Comment: Given that "All created classes extend another class, either explicitly or implicitly", what does `Object` extend? or is that the exception to the rule? Not wishing to be pedantic, just curious

Comment: @chrisbunney With the notable exception of Object.

Comment: Haha, touche.  All except one. :)  Though I intended "created classes" to come across as "user-created, custom, non-core Java classes".

Comment: @chrisbunney `Object` does not extend anything. In Java, Object is the exception to the rule, and the VM/compiler has to know the path to the Object class to run.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible for you to inject your own Object implementation by mucking with the boot classpath.  However, I don't think there is any way to use a base object other than Object.  You could try some byte code manipulation, but it is entirely possible that your modified class will be rejected by the class loader.

Comment: This amounts to "replacing the current hierarchy", which the OP said he didn't want to do.  He wants to be able to use both simultaneously.  This is definitely really interesting, though.  I might try this in my spare time and see how it goes. :)

Comment: @Jeff - yes, i realize what i suggested is not exactly what the OP wants.  i said as much in my answer.